# How to include attributed filtered with JsonFilter in spring controller?

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, jackson, fasterxml

I need to filter some attribute only in one controller.

Fasterxml JsonFilter works when I used it with ObjectMapper in the controller as follow

```
FilterProvider filter2 = new SimpleFilterProvider().addFilter("somefilter",
SimpleBeanPropertyFilter.filterOutAllExcept("prop1","prop2"));
```

With object like

```
@JsonFilter("somefilter")
public class Bar{
String prop1;
String prop2;
String prop3;
}
```

But when trying to return the same object with spring controller

```
 @RequestMapping(value = "/path", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    protected @ResponseBody Foo handleGet( ..
```

where

```
public class Foo{
Bar p1;
Bar p2;
}
```

the Bar attribute are omitted completely. In this case we need to return the Object unfiltered.

I have to use the object mapper in the controller to return the whole object.

Is there a way  to disable the filter for the controller ?

Comment: You mean you're trying to skip some fields on your Bar object to be serialised?

Comment: Yes, skip the serialization when ObjectMapper is used. But serialize everything in the controller.

Comment: And when the controller uses it, you want to display the fields?  Sorry, I can't edit my previous comment.

Comment: Have you tried `@JsonIgnoreProperties` instead of filter?

Comment: that is different.

Answer (score 1):

You can try `MappingJacksonValue` to set Jackson filter provider to serialize the POJO with in Spring controller.

From the source code of [AbstractJackson2HttpMessageConverter](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/blob/00d2606b000f9bdafbd7f4a16b6599fb51b53fa4/spring-web/src/main/java/org/springframework/http/converter/json/AbstractJackson2HttpMessageConverter.java):

```
protected void writeInternal(Object object, Type type, HttpOutputMessage outputMessage)
        throws IOException, HttpMessageNotWritableException {
    ...
    try {
        ...
        if (object instanceof MappingJacksonValue) {
            MappingJacksonValue container = (MappingJacksonValue) object;
            ...
            filters = container.getFilters();
        }
        ...
        ObjectWriter objectWriter;
        if (serializationView != null) {
            objectWriter = this.objectMapper.writerWithView(serializationView);
        }
        else if (filters != null) {
            objectWriter = this.objectMapper.writer(filters);
        }
        else {
            objectWriter = this.objectMapper.writer();
        }
        ...
        objectWriter.writeValue(generator, value);
        ...
    }
```

It should be possible to reset the `FilterProvider` in `objectMapper` by filters set in `MappingJacksonValue`. In your case, you can try something like follows:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/foo", method = RequestMethod.GET)
protected @ResponseBody MappingJacksonValue handleGet(...) {
    MappingJacksonValue mappingJacksonValue = new MappingJacksonValue(foo);    
    FilterProvider filter = new SimpleFilterProvider().addFilter("somefilter", SimpleBeanPropertyFilter.serializeAllExcept());
    mappingJacksonValue.setFilters(filter);
    return mappingJacksonValue;
}
```

If you only have one controller require to filter out properties from `Bar`, you may also consider to add filter for the particular controller instead of setting it into the ObjectMapper:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/bar", method = RequestMethod.GET)
protected @ResponseBody MappingJacksonValue handleGet(...) {
    MappingJacksonValue mappingJacksonValue = new MappingJacksonValue(bar);    
    FilterProvider filter = new SimpleFilterProvider().addFilter("somefilter", SimpleBeanPropertyFilter.filterOutAllExcept("prop1","prop2"));
    mappingJacksonValue.setFilters(filter);
    return mappingJacksonValue;
}
```